# Build Gradle failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I recently updated my Android Studio to ver 3.0.1 and when i tried to open my old project to extend for more functionality. During start up it was stuck in Gradle Building, so i looked for some solutions and then i tried this one. ([this link](https://cafe2311.wordpress.com/2017/11/15/android-studio-3-0-stuck-at-building-gradle-project-info/))

Now studio is able to open my project, then i updated some dependencies as per requirements and tried to sync but this comes out,

```
C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-auth-11.0.4.aar\130bbdf2e58a977ac16e514bcd3a274f\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-auth-11.0.4.aar\130bbdf2e58a977ac16e514bcd3a274f\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.

C:\Users\3537\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.0.4.aar\a2c4fe108b0bd423ffb8601a316a793a\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.


Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

It all says file not found but when i checked into that directory all files are there.

My Gradle files...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.purvik.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'

// FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.2.0'

// FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.2.0'
enter code here
// FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If anyone is having any idea then comment back so i can resolve it.

EDITED:

So many thing tried. Later i created a new project in new window. Then see what dependency it takes by default. Copied it and update that version in my old project build.gradle file. One by one i was adding dependencies to my new project if it gets successful build i'll update old dependency to that version. This resolve my dependency mismatch errors.

Most important inside module gradle.properties file add,

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

line so it will not look for those png file errors. (found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46988596/5228412)) That's how now I'm able to create successful build of old project. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the gradle version to 27, or manually delete the gradle caches

Comment: I did that so but that didn't work for me. I have updated my question how i'm currently able to build gradle.

Answer (score 0):

AAPT2 does has an issue with long paths (> ca.140 characters) or with paths with non-ascii characters. Here it looks like it's caused by the long paths. This has been fixed, but not released yet, so the current workaround for you is either to move the cache directory closer to the C: root or to disable AAPT2 for now. The fix should be released soon.